# how to keep centered icon & label BottomNavigationView in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using bottom BottomNavigationView in andoid. But When is used labeled visible ,between icon & label grap is big. Besides icon is bit top. How to adjust it
Here is my image
[image]

Here is my xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/bottom_nav_height_base"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:itemIconSize="@dimen/bottom_navigation_icon_size_base"
    app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

   </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is my Activity:

```
 val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
    val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
        setOf(
            R.id.navigation_home,
            R.id.navigation_notifications,
            R.id.navigation_account,
            R.id.navigation_settings
        )
    )
    val bottomNavigationView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
    bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    bottomNavigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)
```

Can you help BottomNavigationView icon & label centered ? or suggest me to customize the BottomNavigationView

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
android:layout_height="@dimen/bottom_nav_height_base"
```

Try:

```
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```